# Spring @Transactional Data getting committed to DB middle in the process

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am working on Spring declarative transactional handling assignment.

My question is, Data is flushing to the middle in the transactional process. I only set data to a freshly created object with 'new' operator. For setting the data I hit DB and have to fetch some data. After executing the setter methods half ways it flushes the some data

Ex:
Contact contact = DB.loadContact(); -> select query

Consignment.setContact (contact);

-> when the execution pass this line the data is committed to DB

Please refer the code below for further understanding

```
// code 01

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void editInternationalExportConsigment (){

    // calling a nested method
    internationalExportConnoteFormToDomainTranslator.translate(exportConssignmentWrapper, user);
..........
}



 //code 02
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public InternationalConsignment translate(AbstractFormWrapper defaultWrapper, Person user)  {

    // set values to a newly created object

   consignment.setSenderContact(contact);
        consignment.setCustomerReference(consignmentVO.getCustomerRef());

    // I have called no insert or update calls in the middle, 
    //There are only select queries hit the db middle in the process and those also execute under transactional scope.

     Contact contact = 
 inquiry.loadCustomerContactById(consignmentVO.getCustomerContactId().intValue());

    // when executing this line, it commit the Data to DB
   consignment.setContact(contact);
   ...........
   ...........
   }
```

---

I used following way to monitor transaction and, logger shows same active transaction through process

```
logger.error("######Method Name ==="+str+"==="+ Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
            logger.error("######Transaction Name ==="+str+"==="+TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName());
            logger.error("######Transaction Active ==="+str+"==="+TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
            logger.error("######Transaction Readonly ==="+str+"==="+ TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly())
```

I am stuck here, Highly appreciate if someone can give me a clue here.

Thanks !

--- detailed code block I have issue --

```
private void translateOrginDestinationInformation(InternationalExportConsignmentFormWrapper consignmentVO, InternationalConsignment consignment, ISVCAIXISInquiry inquiry) {
        Country destination = inquiry.loadCountryById(consignmentVO.getReceiverCountryID());
        consignment.setDestination(destination);
        consignment.setDestinationCity(inquiry.loadByCityId(consignmentVO.getReceiverCityID()));

        TestTransactionIndicatingUtil.testTransactionalStatus("originaldestination translate");
        Contact contact = inquiry.loadCustomerContactById(consignmentVO.getCustomerContactId().intValue());


        if (contact != null && contact.getCity() != null) {
              consignment.setOrgin(contact.getCity().getCountry());
              consignment.setUniqueOriginCountry((contact.getCity().getCountry()!=null)?contact.getCity().getCountry().getId():null);
              consignment.setOrginCity(contact.getCity());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what Consignment.setContact (contact); actually do? can you show this function?

Comment: Contact contact = inquiry.loadCustomerContactById(consignmentVO.getCustomerContactId().intValue());
  
  
  if (contact != null && contact.getCity() != null) {
     consignment.setOrgin(contact.getCity().getCountry());
     consignment.setUniqueOriginCountry((contact.getCity().getCountry()!=null)?contact.getCity().getCountry().getId():null);
     consignment.setOrginCity(contact.getCity());
  }

Comment: You said consignment.setContact(contact); line commit data to db. So I want to see setContact method. Not translateOrginDestinationInformation this method.

Comment: @shanikayrs while reading the post it looks like you use the terms 'flush' and 'commit' interchangeably. However, from Hibernate point of view those two are quite different : Flushing - is the phase when hibernate executes accumulated queries. Transaction - is a property of a DB connection. Hence, it means that during a single DB transaction multiple hibernate flushes might occur, and they will be part of the same transaction. How do you verify that the transaction is actually being committed after the `consignment.setContact(contact)` ?

Comment: @Ruben . thanks for the response. I am debugging my program with breakpoint and have enabled ' hibernate show sql ' . I have put breakpoints to the execution point where I see 'insert/update' and check DB same time. There I see data is committed. If I throw an exception at before exit the transactional method I can see data has been modified partially.